# Tinting background image darker

Tags: html, css, background-image

I've set a background image to an element but would like to tint it so that it is darker.

I'm trying to do it with multiple background images:

```
.c-to-c {
    background: url('https://picsum.photos/535/250') no-repeat, rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The black doesn't show up however, and it's displaying as though there is only the background image.

Comment: hi, have you tried linear-gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then here is an example with `linear-gradient` rule.

```
.c-to-c {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('https://picsum.photos/535/250') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS filter property to apply the tint.

```
.c-to-c {
    background: url('https://picsum.photos/535/250') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

consider using:

```
background-blend-mode: darken;
```

look up 'background-blend-mode' for its extensive list of property values

Answer (score 0):

```
.c-to-c {
background-image: linear-gradient(
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), 
url('/image');
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```

}

This syntax seems to work for the objective you described.